# Seeking Online Resources and Textbook suggestions

Tags: organic-chemistry

I want to learn chemistry, and I want to know if there is an online resource that would provide me with a list of textbooks, telling me the order to read them to bring me from a complete beginner to a college level. I have looked to see if any colleges released their course syllabus so I could follow, but I was unable to find any that also listed the textbooks. I also looked to see if the government has set something in place for self-education, but I was still unable to find anything. If something like what I have described does not exist, and if you still remember what textbooks you read, could you please tell me? Thank you in advance.